# get user permissions with laravel vue rest api

Tags: laravel, vue.js, permissions, roles, laravel-permission

I'm trying to get all user permissions with Laravel for backend and vuejs for frontend.
How can i get this from api to vue? what is the best choice?
I tried to get them with below code but shows me error

In the permissionMixin:

```
import PermissionDataService from '../../Servieces/PermissionDataService'

export default {

    methods: {
        checkPermission() {
            let permissions;
            PermissionDataService.get("user_permissions")
                .then((response) => {
                    permissions= response.data;
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.debug(error)
                });
            return hasAccess;
        }
    }
}
```

and that is how i used it in main.js:

```
import permission from "@/core/mixins/permissionMixin";
Vue.mixin(permission);
window.Laravel = this.checkPermission();

console.debug(Laravel)

Vue.directive('can', function (el, binding) {
    return Laravel.permissions.indexOf(binding) !== -1;
});
```

but always shows me this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "defaults", a.default.axios is undefined
```

I am totally sure the endpoint is ok
ANY Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved.
I had to put

```
window.Laravel = this.checkPermission();
```

into one of layout files